# calculating number of operations in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
total1 = 0
total2 = 0
n = int( input (' Enter the value of n : '))

for x in range(n+1): 
   total1 += x

for y in range(1 , n): 
   total2 += total1*y

print('total1' , total1)
print('total2' , total2)
```

1. I am kinda confused if assignment is considered an operation or not
2. I am not sure how to calculate number of operations in a loop
   for x in range(n+1):
   total1 += x

How do we calculate number of operations here , is this a n + 2 operation because the loop is n+1 and then total1 +=x is another 1 operation, so n+1+1 = n +2

Please kindly shed some light here. Not to sure on how to calculate this ?

Thank you

Comment: "if assignment is considered an operation or not" - yes, it is an operation.

Comment: "how to calculate number of operations in a loop for x in range(n+1): total1 += x" - number of iterations of loop: n operations.

Comment: Since you tagged *big-o*, the actual specific number of operations does not matter, only the order of them. E.g. a loop of O(n) iterations (linear with respect to the input, doesn't matter what linear factors), where each iteration performs O(1) operations (i.e. a constant amount of them, doesn't matter what constant) will have O(n) complexity. See more here: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: total1 += x , so is this considered n  operations or 2 operations  or is it n + 2, which is inside the loop ?

Comment: What counts as an operation is ambiguous. For instance, there are many things happening under the hood when you do `range(n+1)`. We see an addition, but a range object is created with start/end/step attributes that are initialised, ... it is completely a matter of opinion how you count all that. But an exact count is not needed for a complexity analysis. As long as you know what is O(1), it doesn't matter if that consists of 1 operation, 10 operations or 100 operations. So whether you count the loop as n or as 3n + 2 is also irrelevant. It's all O(n), and that is what really counts.

Comment: I believe the 'algorithm' tag is not appropriate here.

Comment: If we're talking strictly about asymptotic Big O analysis, Big O doesn't concern itself with individual 'operations' but rather how the running time of an algorithm / program changes with respect to the input n. The OP needs to understand this distinction

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 operations at the beginning:

```
total1 = 0
total2 = 0
n = int( input (' Enter the value of n : '))
```

Then for the first loop

```
for x in range(n+1): 
   total1 += x
```

you have `n + 1` calls of `range` and n assignments.

For the second loop:

```
for y in range(1 , n): 
   total2 += total1*y
```

you have n calls of range + (n-1) multiplications + (n-1) assignments.

So, totally we get:

```
3 + (n+1) + n + n + 2*(n-1) = 
3*n + 2*n + 4 - 2 = 
5*n + 2
```

Actually, this calculation is not fully correct as `range` call is not an atomic operation. But we can ignore it as it doesn't have an inner loop inside the function. Your algorithm has O(n) complexity.

I recommend you to read chapter 3 of the book "Introduction to algorithms" by Cormen et al.